# Setting JAVA_HOME when running Ant from Java

Tags: java, ant, javac

The reason is long and boring, but I need to run an Ant script to compile Java 1.5 code from a Java 1.4 app.  I keep getting this error, though:

```
BUILD FAILED

build.xml:16: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\j2sdk1.4.2_16\jre"
```

In my code, I have:

```
Project p = new Project();
p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
p.setProperty("java.home", "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_04");
p.fireBuildStarted();
p.init();
// so on and so forth
```

but it ignores it.  I've also tried p.setUserProperty(String, String), but that doesn't do the trick, either.  Is there a way to do it without launching a separate process?

Comment: FYI: `java.home` must be set to `$JAVA_HOME/jre`, not to `$JAVA_HOME` itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does the javac task in your buildfile have `fork="yes"`? If not, then it doesn't matter what the `java.home` property is set to; ant will attempt to call the javac `Main` method in the same java process, which from your error is a JRE, not a JDK.

**EDIT** Try setting the `executable` property of your javac task to the full path to the `javac` binary and add `compiler="extJavac"` to the task.

Comment: Adding fork="yes" does help -- at least javac runs, but it's still the wrong version.

Comment: I was looking for something like the "executable" property and just didn't see it.  It's annoying that I have to set it for each javac task, but it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the backslashes be doubled?

```
p.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_04");
```

Comment: They were.  I think something went wrong when pasting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set environment variables JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME properly? If you are setting via code it should work though.

Also check if your %JAVA_HOME%\bin directory %ANT_HOME%\bin should be in the environment variable 'path'.

Your problem seems to be with the %JAVA_HOME%\bin not being present in the envt. variable path though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make this work is to add 'tools.jar' to your classpath. The javac compiler is contained within this jar.

java -cp $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar ...

Answer (score 0):

javac option is available in tools.jar. In eclipse, even if your JRE HOME points to a jdk, all the system libraries point to JDK_HOME\jre\lib. There is no tools.jar. You can add tools.jar as an external Jar file. This should solve your issue