# Is junit-addons compatible with Junit4.x?

Tags: java, junit

According to the [SourceForge project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/junit-addons/) page, junit-addons is compatible with Junit 3.7 and 3.8. Does anyone know if this will work with Junit4.x? If not, are there any alternative libraries with HTML reporting functions*?

*I am trying to avoid using Ant for this, as my client wishes against using Ant.

Comment: The code for junit addons seems to date from 2003, so I very much doubt it is compatible with junit 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think junit-addons is compatible with junit 4, it certainly doesn't look it from the sourceforge page you displayed.

I would recommend using ant or maven. If invoking the command line version of ant is a problem, you could always look at embedding it. See the answers to [Run ant from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733684/run-ant-from-java) for a good starting point.

Comment: I ended up going with Ant even though it "wasn't an option". Seems the client didn't really care about using Ant as long as the build process didn't rely on it.