# Run Ant from Java with build file from InputStream

Tags: java, ant

I want to run Ant scripts from within a Java program. For this I found
[Run ant from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6733684/run-ant-from-java)
but it requires the build.xml to reside in the filesystem. However I'd like to run the build script either to be on the classpath (inside a jar) or maybe even come via the network.

Is it possible to make Ant process a build script coming via an InputStream?

Comment: I could be wrong but I suspect not. A thorough search of the javadoc for Ant itself should confirm it. A workaround would be to create a temp file

Comment: http://fikin-ant-tasks.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/fikin/ant/EmbeddedAntProject.html might be worth a look.

Comment: @g00se Thank you. I am aware of the workaround but wanted to take it directly to the classpath.

Comment: @martinclayton Having checked the code it seems that EmbeddedAntProject copies the buidl script into a temporary file before executing it. Well, maybe there is no real answer to my problem...